# Regex to strip initial and terminating strings and replace strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that *may* begin with one or more `%0D%0A`, and also *may* end with one or more `%0D%0A`.  I want to strip any of those `%0D%0A` sequences from the string using regex.

To complicate it a little, the ASCII text between any possible initial or terminating `%0D%0A` sequences may also contain one or more `%0D%0A` strings, which need to be converted to `,%20` (comma space).

I would prefer to do this with a single regex, but if it needs to be two regex's that is acceptable.

As an example, for any of these strings:

```
x=%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ahello, world%0D%0A%0D%0A
x=%0D%0Ahello, world%0D%0A%0D%0A
x=hello, world%0D%0A
x=hello, world%0D%0A%0D%0A
x=%0D%0A%0D%0Ahello, world
x=%0D%0A%0D%0Ahello%0D%0Aworld%0D%0A
x=%0D%0Ahello%0D%0Aworld%0D%0A%0D%0A
x=hello%0D%0Aworld%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A
```

I would like the output to be:
`x=hello, world`

This is what I have written so far to strip the initial and terminating `%0D%0A` sequences, but it does not work:
`x=((?:%0D%0A)+(.*)|(.*)(?:%0D%0A)+|(?:%0D%0A)+(.*?)(?:%0D%0A)+)`

Note that the `x=` is just arbitrary text that needs to be preserved.

**Update:**
My apologies; I did not want to overwhelm everyone with too many details, but the lack of them is resulting in helpful answers that won't work.  I'm sorry.

What I'm doing is using a javascript browser extension that replaces one string with another.  All I can provide to the extension is a regex pattern to match, and a replacement output string (which uses $1, $2, $3, etc. as matching sequences).

For example, if it receives a string of
`helloworld`
and I tell it to replace regex `hello.*` with `good$1`,
it will output `goodworld`.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Aditya Per your request, I have posted examples.

Comment: What's the significance of this %0D%0A? Pardon my lack of knowledge

Comment: @Aditya It's the encoded version of `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard you shown how input looks, add the output also

Comment: @Tushar "I would like the output to be: x=hello, world"

Comment: @Ja͢ck who's the OP then?

Comment: @Aditya Not sure what you mean by that question; I'm merely responding to the comments, because they can be logically deduced from the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 : Remove starting and ending occurences**

(^(%0D%0A)+)|((%0D%0A)+$)

In javascript you would write `x = x.replace(/(^(%0D%0A)+)|((%0D%0A)+)$/g, '');`

**Step 2 : Replace intermediate occurences of the group by comma**

^.+(%0D%0A)+.+$

Comment: It matches any `%xx%xx` in the target string, anywhere; no anchors; requiring at least two of such sequences with at least one character in between ... this doesn't derive from the question very well.

Comment: OP finally added the examples. Let me see what to modify next

Comment: @RockPaperLizard how about just removing all occurrences of "%0D%0A"? Won't it work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  If I do that, I won't be able to covert that sequence to a comma if it occurs in the middle of the string.

Comment: Based on your logic, I created this regex: `x=((?:%0D%0A)+(.*)|(.*)(?:%0D%0A)+$)` and I replace it with `x=$1$2`.  I get an infinite recursion error when testing on the string `x=%0D%0Ahello`

Answer (score 0):

You would need two replace operations:

1. trim the string on both sides, i.e. replace `^(?:%0D%0A)+|(?:%0D%0A)+$` with nothing
2. translate the remaining occurrences, i.e. replace `%0D%0A` with `", "`

```js
var x = '%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ahello, world%0D%0A%0D%0A';
    
x = x.replace(/^(?:%0D%0A)+|(?:%0D%0A)+$/g, '');
x = x.replace(/%0D%0A/g, ', ');
   
alert(x);
```

Comment: Thanks. My question did not initially have enough specifics, and so it's my fault your answer will not work. My apologies. I cannot use the `replace` javascript function; I updated the question to explain why.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard You can just use the regular expressions, you don't have to use `.replace()` at all.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard To illustrate the workings of the bigger expression, check out [the explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cY2mF6/1).